# WatiN get DOM element position in Firefox and IE

Tags: c#, .net, watin

How to get DOM element position in WatiN Framework? Or how get mshtml.IHTMLElement from WatiN?
I need to move mouse cursor to one of Div.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this page...

http://khemlall.info/2011/07/21/how-to-move-mouse-hover-over-obout-controls-using-watin-framework/

I can verify it works, but only for IE (and we're using Firefox :S)

**EDIT** The reason I was looking for this is because on the site I'm testing I need to verify a popup which only appears when the user hovers the mouse over a specific link.  The way I got around it was to simply call: -

```
myLink.FireEvent("mouseover");
myLink.FireEvent("mousemove");
```